# WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic - during apt-get upgrade - how to fix?

Tags: upgrade, initramfs, firmware

followed by:

```
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_McREc1/lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_McREc1/lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_McREc1/lib/modules is certainly missing. Can I recreate it?

I was doing an apt-get upgrade, which completed with those warnings.
The referenced duplicate applies to an update-initramfs which I was not doing (intentionally).  Perhaps this is implied by apt-get upgrade?

Subsequent apt-get upgrade completes without those warnings.  I'm just concerned that the firmware was not updated but other modules were.

Comment: do you have linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic installed?

Comment: How would I find out if I have linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic installed?

Comment: I have NOT run sudo update-initramfs -u -k all.  Should I have?

Comment: what were you doing when you got the error? APT may have called `update-initramfs`. You can check if software is installed with `apt policy linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic`

Comment: apt policy linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic returns:
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-59.80
  Version table:
     4.4.0-59.80 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages

Comment: then it's not installed. Did you try the answer of the linked post?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.